# Using `lapply` with a S4 object and a custom function with 2 arguments

Tags: r, list, function, lapply, r-s4

I'm trying to execute my own function named `myfun(x,y)` on a S4 object using `lapply()`, but don't know if it's the appropriate way to do it.

My S4 object `dblist` contains 3 slots and I would like to fill the empty plot `df.para` using my function that takes in arguments `df.list` and `df.para`. (the argument `df.para` is used to create sub slot (e.g. $Name ; $Eval ...etc))

So I tried this :

```
> lapply(dblist@df.list, myfun(x,y) , y=dblist@df.para)  
Error: object 'x' not found
```

Here is a description of the object `dblist` :

```
> str(dblist)
Formal class 'dblist' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
  ..@ df.list :List of 102
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 81 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Parametre: Factor w/ 81 levels "1.","10.","11.",..: 77 79 76 80 74 81 75 78 1 13 ...
  .. .. ..$ valeur1  : Factor w/ 69 levels "","1/2-1/2","1522",..: 55 27 5 11 20 4 3 2 24 26 ...
  .. .. ..$ valeur2  : Factor w/ 73 levels "","]","a6","b5",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 28 21 
...  
.. .. [list output truncated]
  ..@ df.para : list()
  ..@ df.coups: list()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your `lapply` function is not clear enough on what the arguments to `myfun` are. Try this:

```
lapply(X=dblist@df.list, FUN=myfun(x=X,y) , y=dblist@df.para)
```